# Макрос напоминания с выводом сообщения

Tags: excel, vba, office

Здравствуйте!
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема или подскажите как это реализовать правильно.
Нужно выводить сообщения, после прохождения определенного времени от указанного в ячейке.

Например: вводим 11:30 в ячейке А1, через 30 минут от указанного времени (т.е. в 12) появляется сообщения, после через час от указанного времени (12:30) другое сообщение и т.п.

В программировании для Excel и VBA не силен, но смог соорудить такой примитивный макрос, который вывод сообщения, правда оно выводится каждый раз по 2 раза, а как сделать чтобы сообщение выводилось только 1 раз, понять не могу.

```
Sub Напоминание()

' Сочетание для запуска: Ctrl+Shift+A

timeStart = TimeValue(Format(Range("A1"), "h:m:s"))
firstAlarm = timeStart + CDate("00:30:00")
secondAlarm = timeStart + CDate("01:00:00")
Application.OnTime firstAlarm, "Alarm"
Application.OnTime secondAlarm, "secAlarm"
End Sub
Sub Alarm()
MsgBox "Сообщение 1"
End Sub
Sub secAlarm()
MsgBox "Сообщение 2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то никак понять не могу. Описание поведения есть лишь в примере:

> Например: вводим 11:30 в ячейке А1, через 30 минут от указанного
>   времени (т.е. в 12) появляется сообщения, после через час от
>   указанного времени (12:30) другое сообщение и т.п.

И по нему процедуру напоминания необходимо выполнить 2 раза. Далее, вы, в приведенном листинге добились этого, но не нравится то, что напоминание выполняется 2 раза. Так что надо?

Если второе напоминание должно срабатывать только в некоторых (пока не понятных) ситуациях, так обрабатывайте эти ситуации и ставьте/убирайте нужный/ненужный таймер.

К примеру, если второе напоминание должно сработать только в случае отмены первого, то выводите в первом диалог, по реакции пользователя на который можно будет следать вывод, нужен ли второй таймер. Тут уж или отменяйте ранее установленный второй таймер, благо, функционал имеется в том же [Application.OnTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx). Или же, наоборот, первоначально устанавливайте только один таймер, и по реакции пользователя на первый, при необходимости, запускайте второй таймер. Помоему, второй вариант более предпочтителен.